# Setting id to a panel control in gridview

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a panel control in gridview's template.
I need to hide/unhide panel in javascript function, for that i need to pass panel's id to the javascript.

The problem is that all panels have the same id in gridview, so I need to set unique id to each panel.
I tried to do:

```
<asp:Panel id= "Panel_<%# Eval("ID")%>"
```

and some other variations but always get an error.

The panel contains some other controls, I need it to be server side because I need to set at code-behind (after checking if user is authenticated)

What can I do?

p.s.
It doesn't have to be Panel, any other control that I can find with Findcontrol and can hold other controls.

**Update:**

```
I set the the js event in code behind:
protected void gvw_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {

     if (UserIsAuthenticated)
     { 
         HyperLink title = e.Row.FindControl("lnkTitle") as HyperLink; 
        Panel panel = e.Row.FindControl("panel") as Panel; 
        title.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ShowHidePanel(" + panel.ClientID +")");
        //All get the same id!!!
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use server-side control's ids in javascript you should use [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property of the control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidePanel(panelId){
    var panel = document.getElementById(panelId);
    panel.style.display = 'none';    
}
</script>
```

So you can use it in some handler like `hidePanel(<%=panel.ClientID%>);`.

Comment: if you do this inside the gridview, then you'll end up with N `hidePanel()` functions.

Comment: @Martin you are right. Updated to have N `hidePanel()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, to set the panel's id to a unique value, you should use this (note the use of single- and double-quotes):

```
<asp:Panel id='<%# "Panel_" + Eval("ID") %>'
```

Although, this will probably still not help, because the client-side ID will be composed from from the IDs of the panel's parent controls and the panel's ID, e.g. `ctl00_MyGridView_Panel_1`.

As an alternative, you could set the `CssClass` property of the panel to a unique value (since this will not be changed by ASP.NET) and then use client-side code based to select the panel. E.g. when using jquery:

```
$('Panel_1').click( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let ASP.NET generate the ID for you. Then, use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property.

As long as it's in the same template column, you should be able to use it directly there. Something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="MyGridViewPanel" runat="server" style="display:none;">Hello World!</asp:Panel>
<a href='javascript:open_the_panel(<%=MyGridViewPanel.ClientID%>);'>Open the panel</a>
```

Comment: as i wrote in question, this is inside gridview... all panels has the same id and clientid

Comment: They won't have the same ClientID. That is what the client id is for. It will be rendered with a unique ID and the ClientID property is how you access the unique id.

Comment: If I set the event (attributes.add) in the codebehind, the get the same ids.